# Wrong line wrap when converting Markdown pipe table to Word/docx

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I am trying to convert a document written in Markdown `*.md` to Word `*.docx` using pandoc, but am having trouble setting the widths of table columns. As I understand the [pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables), it should be possible to use the `pipe_tables` extension and `--columns` flag to specify relative column widths within which cell contents should wrap:

> If a pipe table contains a row whose printable content is wider than the column width (see --columns), then the table will take up the full text width and the cell contents will wrap, with the relative cell widths determined by the number of dashes in the line separating the table header from the table body.

Consider this `mcve.md`:

```
||||
|-|-|---|
| 20% | this_column_should_take_up_20%_of_the_table_width | this column should take up 60% of the table's total width |
```

converted using the following command:

```
pandoc --from=markdown+pipe_tables --to=docx --columns=5 mcve.md -o mcve.docx
```

The resulting Word table has no wrapping of the middle column, with a narrow first column, and a narrow wrapped third column - not the expected relative widths or wrapping:

[image: screenshot of converted Word table]

By manually setting column widths in Word using the `Layout -> AutoFit -> Fixed Column Width` toolbar, I can reproduce the desired behaviour - but I'm really looking to automate this using pandoc.

[image: screenshot of manually modified Word table]

If converting from Markdown to PDF, [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4239) explains how something similar to the desired output can be achieved.

Am I understanding the documentation wrong, or is there a way to do something similar when converting to `*.docx` format?

For info, this is the `--version` output for my `pandoc` command:

```
pandoc 1.19.2.4
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.17.0.5, texmath 0.9.4.4, skylighting 0.3.3.1
```

and I'm using MS Word for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11328.20362)

Answer (score 0):

The key from the documentation is:

> the relative cell widths determined by the number of dashes in the line

So your table is formatted corrrectly, maybe a bit more human-readable version:

```
|            |            |                                    |
|------------|------------|------------------------------------|
| 20%        | this_column_should_take_up_20%_of_the_table_width | this column should take up 60% of the table's total width |
```

But you should try to update to the [newest pandoc version](https://pandoc.org/installing.html).

Comment: I agree that my markdown is not particularly readable, this was the shortest text to get the desired relative spacing (total of 5 dashes should give columns with relative widths of 1/5, 1/5 and 3/5). Manually updating to the latest version (2.7.3) and running with your markdown text still gives me the same result in Word as before.

Comment: hm.. you sure it's the right version? `pandoc -v`... or try `-t native` to see whether the tables widths are encoded in the pandoc document AST... I don't have word installed to test the output. might also depend on the word version? if nobody else answers here.. maybe try pandoc-discuss

Comment: my guess would be that it works in normal word, but not Office 365. if you can post a minimal docx file that works in Office 365, please submit an issue to https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues

Comment: I'll give all of that a go and report back, thanks for the help so far

Comment: I suspect you're right that the problem lies with the Office 365 version of Word. I don't have an older version of Word to test with, but uploading the document to Google Drive and opening it there, displays a table with the expected column spacing. Then converting it to Google's native format, downloading as  docx and opening _that_ file in Office 365's Word displays correctly... I'll use the Google generated file to submit an issue